# How can I create and use a stream of Pairs with Akka Streams for java?

Tags: java, stream, akka, akka-stream

Im trying to use the javadsl variant of [Akka streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC2/java.html?_ga=1.165434239.1516064727.1430988896), and I seem to have hit a problem when I try to define a Flow which should take [Pair](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.japi.Pair) elements.

Say, for example, I have defined a Flow which accepts incoming Strings and Pairs it with a boolean stating wether or not the String has a length of 5 or bigger:

```
final Flow<String, Pair<String, Boolean>, BoxedUnit> stringToPair = Flow
    .of(String.class)
    .map(s -> new Pair<>(s, s.length() >= 5));
```

This works fine. 
But the next step is for me to define a Flow which takes Pairs of String and Boolean and returns just the String again:

```
final Flow<Pair<String, Boolean>, String, BoxedUnit> pairToString = Flow
        .of(Pair.class)
        .map(p -> p.first());
```

I am not sure if I should create the pairToString flow with the .of(Pair.class) method because I dont know if and where the incoming Pair should be typed (like `Pair<String, Boolean>`)

Any help and / or pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generic stream element types you can create a Flow using

```
Flow.<Pair<String, Boolean>> create()
```

which allows more freedom in this regard than `Flow.of(...)`. Which one to choose is a matter of taste in all non-generic cases.

Comment: Excellent, it works! I was confused on how to get the syntax correct.
Thank you!